# how to remove header while copying from excel using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript

can I please know how to copy data from excel workbook to another excel workbook without  header. I am able to writ the code for copying but don't know how to avoid header. And how to make the last cell of the last row active.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Record your steps and let excel write it for you. Tools - Macros - Record.

End key -  down arrow. end key - right arrow gets you to last cell.